# How to get form values on submit?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="dome" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment1"/>
    <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment2"/>
    <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment3"/>
    <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment4"/>
</form>
```

I know I can send multiple inputs with the same name and have them save into an array by adding empty square brackets to the input name like in the code.

Now I would like to get the all the values in JavaScript for validation on submit. 
 I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
var comment_list = document.forms["dome"]["comment[]"].value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to loop through the array and check any element is empty or not for validation as below.**

```js
var inps = document.getElementsByName('comment[]');
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
  var inp=inps[i];
  if(!inp.value){
    alert('Enter value for box ' + (i +  1));
  }
}
```

```html
 <form name="dome" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment1"/>
      <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment2"/>
      <input type="text" name="comment[]" value=""/>
      <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment4"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of `comment_list` is a `nodeList`. You have to iterate over it. e.g:

```js
var comments = [];

var comment_list = document.forms["dome"]["comment[]"].forEach(function(el) {
  comments.push(el.value);
});

console.log(comments);
```

```html
<form name="dome" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment1"/>
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment2"/>
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment3"/>
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment4"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` to `validateForm` and this will contain content of your form. You can then convert it to array and map values from your form. As an alternative, you can map `document.forms["dome"]["comment[]"]` to get values.

See the following demo (I added submit button and you have to open browser console to see result as submit clears the output - last element of `formcontent` is that button)

```js
function validateForm(formcontent) {
  let arr = Array.from(formcontent).map(({value}) => ({value}));
  console.log("formcontent:",JSON.stringify(arr))

  let alternative = Array.from(document.forms["dome"]["comment[]"]).map(({value})=>({value}));
  console.log('document.forms["dome"]["comment[]"]:', JSON.stringify(alternative));
}
```

```html
<form name="dome" onsubmit="validateForm(this)" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment1" />
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment2" />
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment3" />
  <input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment4" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```